# "Sort by newest"'s labeling is confusing

Tags: bug

[image: screenshot]

(https://askubuntu.com/users/389450/script-kitten?tab=questions&sort=newest).

The labeling on the right is confusing, and in my humble opinion should rather report "**edited** jan 01 at 00:00 [...]", since the date / time reported is the date / time *of the last edit*.

As it currently stands, it looks like those on the right are the questions' creation dates, since the questions are being sorted by newest; personally I wouldn't expect to read the date / time of the last edit.

Comment: I agree about it being confusing, but I don't think changing it to `"edited jan 01 at 00:00 [...]` would be viable. The date is for the last activity, not just the last edit. The activity can be anything, like answering the question, editing an answer, adding a bounty, etc. You can view the question tab in my profile as they have a bit more activity: http://askubuntu.com/users/8698/dan?tab=questions&sort=newest

Comment: @Dan Then "**last activity** jan 01 at 00:00 [...]"? (This IMO proves that it's even more confusing). I mean, it's not a *big* deal, but I suppose that changing the labeling wouldn't be either.

Comment: I think you should change this to a feature request. Also, the "format" of the text already exists in the site. For example on the homepage it already says "modified [date] [user] [user's rep]" or "answered [date] [user] [user's rep]" etc.

Answer (score 2):

No, the questions are being sorted by creation date. The times listed (the ones you have highlighted) are the modification times:

[image]
[image]

So, the question listed below the one dated August 21 was created on August 6.

Comment: Right, that thing is confusing me. Sorry about that. See the update. My point is mostly changing the labeling.

Comment: @kos I think you're still misunderstanding. The questions *are* sorted by creation date. Newest questions are listed first. Only the dates shown are modification dates. The labelling is correct.

Comment: Sorry about that again. Should be clear now.